# Achieving MQ functionality on z/OS using ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, ibm-mq, zos, cics

I am trying to validate if the WebsphereMQ feature (MQ Triggering) for remote execution of commands on z/OS can be achieved using ActiveMQ. Broadly, I think this will require custom java coding to leverage new frameworks/libs like JCICS (I think this needs CICS Tx Gateway v4.2).Broadly, need to validate the below steps :
a) Install ActiveMQ on z/OS
b) Write Java code to invoke the CKTI Task Initiator or Trigger Monitor in CICS to execute a command on z/OS using JCICS.

I Need to validate the above and correct or add new steps.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you write Java code to invoke CKTI in order to start a CICS transaction?  If your Java code is running, can't you use the issue() method of [StartRequest](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v5r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.jcics.javadoc/com/ibm/cics/server/StartRequest.html&resultof=%2522%2553%2574%2561%2572%2574%2552%2565%2571%2575%2565%2573%2574%2522%2520%2522%2573%2574%2561%2572%2574%2572%2565%2571%2575%2565%2573%2574%2522%2520) to start a CICS transaction?

I think your design will turn out to be...

1. message arrives on ActiveMQ
2. send HTTP message to CICS
3. URIMAP definition causes your JCICS code to be invoked
4. JCICS code does a StartRequest.issue() to begin business logic
5. Send a response to original HTTP message indicating success or failure of issue()

Comment: What I meant was call the JCICS Java api. JCICS is java right ? Also, we will make this call 'from' java code which needs to be running on z/OS, most probably as a MessageListener for onMessage()....

Comment: JCICS is the interface to the CICS API for Java code.  Your Java code running *inside of CICS* can use JCICS to request CICS services.  You mention wanting to "execute a command on z/OS" - what is it you want to do?

Comment: Readup on either of these : WMQ Triggering (Websphere MQ perspective) and/or CICS Task Initiator (CICS perspective). These are standard use cases / usage scenarios.